# Ember Testing: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of null

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli

It appears that `store` is not available in my Ember tests, whether in the context of an `ObjectController` or within any unit tests.  My unit test:

```
`import {test, moduleFor} from "ember-qunit"`
`import DS from "ember-data"`

moduleFor "controller:register", "RegisterController", {
}

test "store is working", ->
    expect 1
    controller = @subject()
    Ember.run(->
        sampleUser = controller.get("store").createRecord("user", {
            username: "myuser"
            password: "otherpassword"
        })
        ok(sampleUser instanceof DS.Model)
    )
```

The test will give:

> Died on test #1     at test
>   (`http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73539:13`)
>       at eval (app/tests/unit/controllers/register-test.js:19:5)
>       at requireModule (`http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54:29`)
>       at `http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:14:29`: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of null

Can anyone explain why I am not able to access `DS` capabilities from either within my tests or from within the controller itself (when running tests)?

Comment: Could you create an instance of the store manually -then inject that /add that to your controller (under test) to verify this works as you'd expect?

Answer (score 1):

Because ember-qunit doesn't inject the store into your controllers, it's meant for unit tests, not integration tests.  And Ember Data's store is outside of the scope of that controller.

Comment: Ok, then how do I fix?

Comment: What is it you are trying to test here?  Ember Data?  I'd add the unit tests to Ember Data's framework instead of in yours.  It's the same as testing jQuery.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/store/create_record_test.js

Comment: Hmmm ... I have quite a few controllers which make calls to the `store` and I would like to prevent my controller unit tests from failing rather than performing an integration test. I imagine this must be a very common scenario. I'm somewhat surprised it isn't addressed directly in the Ember documentation but so be it. @Kingpin2k is there anything you could suggest? I did look at the link sent earlier but I'm afraid I didn't get enough from that to solve this problem.

Comment: inject a fake store on your controller that returns what you're expecting.  Ember-qunit wasn't really built for Ember Data, it was built for Ember, so it doesn't really take Ember Data into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ember-data store to the "needs" section of the unit test.  You will also need to add any models being created to the "needs" section like so:

```
needs: ['service:store', 'model:user']
```

This will inject a real instance of the store into the object (controller, component, route, etc.) being tested.